# Cleaning up Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a lot of extra libraries, include files, dll and libs files in my Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition directory (I was stupid and didn't make a different directory just for additional libraries and put everything in default ones) and I would like to delete ALL EXTRA files that I put there, is there any command available to do so? Or do I need to uinstall it and install it again? (I would really liek to avoid it)

Comment: Perhaps a good opportunity to move ahead, C++ has changed a great deal since the new C++11 standard.  Getting stuck on a 6 year old version of free software doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Build" menu, choose "Clean Solution".

Comment: I did not mean that, I mean from VC 9.0/Includes VC9.0/libs etc.
I need to delete all EXTRA files that I put there like extra include files, dlls etc

In other words I would like to bring my Visual Studio to default state, as fresh as after frist install.